# How do I set the initial node/location for a capacitated vehicle routing problem

Tags: python-3.x, or-tools

I am using Google OR Tools - Vehicle Routing problems wherein I have few parameters which I have to assign like

```
data['distance_matrix']=a
data['num_vehicles'] = no_fos
data['depot'] = 0
data['demands'] = df_user["no_cases"].to_list()
data['vehicle_capacities'] = [75]*no_fos
return data
```

Now I have to define the distance matrix such that I could set the initial node. I have written the code for the same, but still getting same initial and end node as 0.

```
dist = DistanceMetric.get_metric('haversine')

def create_data_model_cap_con(df_user,no_fos):
    """Stores the data for the problem."""
    data = {}
    #data['distance_matrix'] = dist.pairwise(df_user [['lat','lon']].to_numpy())*6373
    
    a = dist.pairwise(df_user_org[['lat','lon']])
    a[:,0] = 0 
    a[0,:] = 0 
    
    
    #A = dist.pairwise(df_user [['lat','lon']].to_numpy())*6373
    #x = np.c_[np.zeros(len(A[0])),A ] 
    #y = np.vstack([np.zeros(len(x[0])),x])
    
    data['distance_matrix']=a
    
    data['num_vehicles'] = no_fos
    data['depot'] = 0
    data['demands'] = df_user["no_cases"].to_list()
    data['vehicle_capacities'] = [75]*no_fos
    return data

def print_solution_cap_con(data, manager, routing, assignment):
    """Prints assignment on console."""
    # Display dropped nodes.
    dropped_nodes = 'Dropped nodes:'
    for node in range(routing.Size()):
        if routing.IsStart(node) or routing.IsEnd(node):
            continue
        if assignment.Value(routing.NextVar(node)) == node:
            dropped_nodes += ' {}'.format(manager.IndexToNode(node))
    print(dropped_nodes)
    # Display routes
    total_distance = 0
    total_load = 0
    for vehicle_id in range(data['num_vehicles']):
        index = routing.Start(vehicle_id)
        plan_output = 'Route for vehicle {}:\n'.format(vehicle_id)
        route_distance = 0
        route_load = 0
        while not routing.IsEnd(index):
            node_index = manager.IndexToNode(index)
            route_load += data['demands'][node_index]
            plan_output += ' {0} Load({1}) -> '.format(node_index, route_load)
            previous_index = index
            index = assignment.Value(routing.NextVar(index))
            route_distance += routing.GetArcCostForVehicle(
                previous_index, index, vehicle_id)
        plan_output += ' {0} Load({1})\n'.format(manager.IndexToNode(index),
                                                 route_load)
        plan_output += 'Distance of the route: {}m\n'.format(route_distance)
        plan_output += 'Load of the route: {}\n'.format(route_load)
        print(plan_output)
        total_distance += route_distance
        total_load += route_load
    print('Total Distance of all routes: {}m'.format(total_distance))
    print('Total Load of all routes: {}'.format(total_load))


def distance_cap_con(x,y,data):
    dis = data['distance_matrix'][x][y]
    return dis

def get_routes_cap_con(solution, routing, manager,df_user,data):
  """Get vehicle routes from a solution and store them in an array."""
  # Get vehicle routes and store them in a two dimensional array whose
  # i,j entry is the jth location visited by vehicle i along its route.
  routes = []
  #routes_dist = []  
  for route_nbr in range(routing.vehicles()):
    index = routing.Start(route_nbr)
    route = [manager.IndexToNode(index)]
    
    while not routing.IsEnd(index):
      index = solution.Value(routing.NextVar(index))
      route.append(manager.IndexToNode(index))
    routes.append(route)
    #routes = get_routes(solution, routing, manager)
    routes_t = pd.DataFrame(routes).T
    col_to_iter = routes_t.columns
    routes_t['route_info'] = routes_t.index
    routes_t = pd.melt(routes_t, id_vars=['route_info'], value_vars=col_to_iter)
    routes_t = routes_t.drop_duplicates(subset='value', keep="first")

    df_user['value'] = df_user.index
    df_user_out = pd.merge(df_user, routes_t, on="value")
    
    df_user_out = df_user_out.sort_values(by=['variable','route_info'])
    df_user_out['route_lag'] = df_user_out.groupby('variable')['value'].shift(-1).fillna(0)
    df_user_out['route_lag'] = df_user_out['route_lag'].astype(np.int64)
    df_user_out['route_info'] = df_user_out['route_info'].astype(np.int64)
    df_user_out['dist'] = df_user_out.apply(lambda row: distance_cap_con(row['route_lag'], row['value'],data), axis=1)
    
  return df_user_out

def get_sol_cap_con(sub_dist_fil,fos_cnt,state_fil):
    df_user_org_sub = df_user_org[(df_user_org.sub_district == sub_dist_fil) & (df_user_org.State == state_fil) ]
    df_user_org_sub.reset_index( inplace=True,drop=True)
    print(sub_dist_fil," no fos",fos_cnt)

    fos_cnt=fos_cnt

    
    
    data = create_data_model_cap_con(df_user_org_sub,fos_cnt)

    # Create the routing index manager.
    manager = pywrapcp.RoutingIndexManager(len(data['distance_matrix']),
                                           data['num_vehicles'], data['depot'])

    # Create Routing Model.
    routing = pywrapcp.RoutingModel(manager)


    # Create and register a transit callback.
    def distance_callback(from_index, to_index):
        """Returns the distance between the two nodes."""
        # Convert from routing variable Index to distance matrix NodeIndex.
        from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
        to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
        return data['distance_matrix'][from_node][to_node]

    transit_callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(distance_callback)

    # Define cost of each arc.
    routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(transit_callback_index)


    def demand_callback(from_index):
        """Returns the demand of the node."""
        # Convert from routing variable Index to demands NodeIndex.
        from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
        return data['demands'][from_node]

    demand_callback_index = routing.RegisterUnaryTransitCallback(
        demand_callback)
    routing.AddDimensionWithVehicleCapacity(
        demand_callback_index,
        0,  # null capacity slack
        data['vehicle_capacities'],  # vehicle maximum capacities
        True,  # start cumul to zero
        'Capacity')
    # Allow to drop nodes.
    penalty = 0
    for node in range(1, len(data['distance_matrix'])):
        routing.AddDisjunction([manager.NodeToIndex(node)], penalty)

    # Setting first solution heuristic.
    search_parameters = pywrapcp.DefaultRoutingSearchParameters()
    #search_parameters.time_limit.seconds = 30
    #search_parameters.solution_limit = 100
    search_parameters.first_solution_strategy = (
        routing_enums_pb2.FirstSolutionStrategy.PATH_CHEAPEST_ARC)
    search_parameters.local_search_metaheuristic = (
        routing_enums_pb2.LocalSearchMetaheuristic.GUIDED_LOCAL_SEARCH)
    #search_parameters.time_limit.FromSeconds(30)


    # Solve the problem.
    solution = routing.SolveWithParameters(search_parameters)

    out_df = get_routes_cap_con(solution, routing, manager,df_user_org_sub,data)

    # Print solution on console.
    #if solution:
    #    print_solution_cap_con(data, manager, routing, solution)
    return   out_df
```

But while running, the initial and end node is the same (which is 0)

Help!

Answer (score 0):

Don't get it, since you are using:

```py
    # Create the routing index manager.
    manager = pywrapcp.RoutingIndexManager(len(data['distance_matrix']),
                                           data['num_vehicles'], data['depot'])
```

this is expected to have '0' as start and end node, otherwise you should use the four parameters version...

```py
# Inside the create_data_model_cap_con() function
data['starts'] = [0,0,1...]
data['ends'] = [1,2,...]
assert(len(data['starts']) == len(data['ends']))
assert(data['num_vehicles'] == len(data['starts']))
...
# Inside the get_sol_cap_con function()
   # Create the routing index manager.
    manager = pywrapcp.RoutingIndexManager(
      len(data['distance_matrix']),
      data['num_vehicles'],
      data['starts']
      data['ends'])
```

documentation: https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/routing_tasks#setting-start-and-end-locations-for-routes

Comment: The solution seems logical but when I am running it, my kernel is getting lost. I had made modifications in the distance matrix also(by setting the 1st row & 1st col. as 0) and omitting the data['depot']. Still also, it is giving the initial node as 0. Is there any other way by which I could specify/set the initial node as the index number of my dataset and keep the end node as 0. Help !